# Why can't apt find Packages file when compressed versions exist?

Tags: apt, package-management

When I execute `apt-get update` on a Precise Ubuntu server I am getting an errors like this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.173 80]
```

This is interesting because the adress contains `Packages.gz` and `Packages.bz2`. From the same server:

```
$ curl http://130.239.18.173/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64</h1>
<pre><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="Icon "> <a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>                        <a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a>      <a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a>  <hr><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"> <a href="/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/">Parent Directory</a>                                 -
<img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"> <a href="Packages.bz2">Packages.bz2</a>                2012-04-26 00:37  1.2M
<img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"> <a href="Packages.gz">Packages.gz</a>                 2012-04-26 00:37  1.6M
<img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"> <a href="Release">Release</a>                     2012-04-26 00:49   97
<hr></pre>
<address>Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) Server at <a href="mailto:ftp-adm@acc.umu.se">ftp.acc.umu.se</a> Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Am I missing some setting to fetch the compressed files instead of the uncompressed `Packages` file? Has the APT repository format changes and I am running an older version of `apt`?

```
$ dpkg -l|grep apt
ii  apt                               0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21           commandline package manager
...
```

...or the least likely reason for this; Has Ubuntu been rolling out corrupt repositories? Could obviously also be an issue with the rsyncing of repositories, but that's probably even less likely.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out something was corrupt in my local apt repository. Resetting it using

```
$ sudo rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

fixed things.